# Visual Studio compilers not visible by cmake

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake-gui

I'm trying to build a program in c++ using mysql.h

So i read that compiling with cmake is necessary. But as it seems cmake cant find visual's studio compilers even though I opened it through Developers command prompt.
This is the error that occurs:

> The C compiler identification is unknown
>
> The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>
> CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
>
> CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
>
> Also, at cmake error list, it says :
>
> Build started 22/12/2016 00:28:42.
>
> The target "_ConvertPdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (34,37)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
>
> The target "_CollectPdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (34,70)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform‌​.targets(57,5):
>   error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141')
>   cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install
>   v141 build tools. Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual
>   Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the
>   solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

Comment: ***The target "_ConvertPdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (34,37)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.*** I see this in some of my CMake builds. It does not seem to cause any issue.

Comment: ***Build started 22/12/2016 00:28:42*** It seems like it is building. ***CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.*** errors usually prevent generation from working.

Comment: it is not building unfortunately...

Comment: Done Building Project "~\target\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the build output after the warnings that you listed.

Comment: you are right, after build failure it says that build tools cannot be found

 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [~\target\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

Comment: I am not sure what the correct platform toolset is for Visual Studio 14 2015 however the V140 / V141 seems like it is part of the problem.

Comment: I think you picked the wrong generator for Visual Studio 14 2015. It looks like the platform toolset 141 is for the Visual Studio 15 2017 RC.

Comment: my visual studio says that its 15 2017. But if I use in cmake visual studio 14 2015 as a compiler, the configuration is done, and BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: That is what I expected. This would be the reason for the compiler detection failure. Because of the wrong generator it was looking for the 2017 RC version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was so desperate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments. The problem was caused by using the wrong generator for `Visual Studio 2015`.

The correct generator for 32 bit code in `Visual Studio 2015` is `Visual Studio 14 2015` and for 64 bit code it is `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64`.